# using flip flop operator to parse a block and regex on a verilog netlist

Tags: perl, verilog

I'm trying to modify a verilog netlist that looks like this:

```
module la_bla ( a b c d);
input a; 
output; 
inout c d;

uHBMN_1  X20 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
nch_mac  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
pch_mac_svt  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
endmodule 

module la_bla2 ( aw b2 c1 dt);
input aw;
output b2;
inout c1 dt;

HBMN_2  X21 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
HBMN_3  X21 (.Z(env), .A(ggg7), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
HBMN_4  X21 (.Z(en5), .A(gg), .Q(qq8), .EN(rr));
HBMN_5  X21 (.Z(en1), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));

endmodule 
.
.
.
.
.
```

Everytime that I find a line that start with a device called :"nch_mac" or pct_mac_svt, I want to add a comment to the ALL module content, but keep  the module statement  and terminals statements ( input , output inout) and endmodule statements untouched. I tried to work with perl flip-flop command:

First, I tried to catch the block that starts with module and finishes with endmodule. Then I tried to capture the device name with regex.

My problem is that required device name can be located anywhere inside the module statement - so how I comment the lines inside the module that comes before it?
I tried something like:

```
while<FILE>{
if(/module/i.../endmodule/i){
   if($_ =~/nch_mac|pch_mac_svt){ $newline=~ s/$_/\/\/$_/}
```

But this didn't work.
I want to get:

```
 module la_bla ( a b c d);
 input a; 
 output; 
 inout c d;

 //uHBMN_1  X20 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
 //nch_mac  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
 //pch_mac_svt  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
 endmodule 

 module la_bla2 ( aw b2 c1 dt);
 input aw;
 output b2;
 inout c1 dt;

 HBMN_2  X21 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
 HBMN_3  X21 (.Z(env), .A(ggg7), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
 HBMN_4  X21 (.Z(en5), .A(gg), .Q(qq8), .EN(rr));
 HBMN_5  X21 (.Z(en1), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));

 endmodule 
 .
 .
 .
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

Store the lines in an array before you decide how you want to print them:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $flag = 1;
my @lines;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/(input|output|inout|\bmodule)/) {
        print;
        $flag = 1;
    }
    elsif (/endmodule/) {
        for my $line (@lines) {
            $line = "//$line" unless $flag;
            print $line
        }
        print;
        @lines = ();
    }
    else {
        push @lines, $_;
        if (/nch_mac|pch_mac_svt/) {
            $flag = 0;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
module la_bla ( a b c d);
input a; 
output; 
inout c d;

uHBMN_1  X20 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
nch_mac  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
pch_mac_svt  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
endmodule 

module la_bla2 ( aw b2 c1 dt);
input aw;
output b2;
inout c1 dt;

HBMN_2  X21 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
HBMN_3  X21 (.Z(env), .A(ggg7), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
HBMN_4  X21 (.Z(en5), .A(gg), .Q(qq8), .EN(rr));
HBMN_5  X21 (.Z(en1), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));

endmodule
```

Here is my exact output:

```
module la_bla ( a b c d);
input a; 
output; 
inout c d;
//
//uHBMN_1  X20 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
//nch_mac  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
//pch_mac_svt  M20 (.G(en), .D(gg), .B(qq), .S(rr));
endmodule 
module la_bla2 ( aw b2 c1 dt);
input aw;
output b2;
inout c1 dt;


HBMN_2  X21 (.Z(en), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
HBMN_3  X21 (.Z(env), .A(ggg7), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));
HBMN_4  X21 (.Z(en5), .A(gg), .Q(qq8), .EN(rr));
HBMN_5  X21 (.Z(en1), .A(gg), .Q(qq), .EN(rr));

endmodule
```

If your input Verilog code is more complicated than that, use a proper parser, such as [Verilog-Perl](https://metacpan.org/release/Verilog-Perl)

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code that I wrote .
it works but it can be improved. for example the line that start with  "module" 
can be expand over few lines ( can be 2 lines, can be 100 lines) but it will always end up with char ";"

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use Getopt::Long;


   my $verilog1=      "/p/ccd/wa/mlea/roodbridgetc/analog/roodbridgetc_9m1z1u/User_libs/libFlow/meny_lo   cal/noam_tc_phy_ana_top/verilog/netlist";
   my $verilog2=  "/p/ccd/wa/mlea/roodbridgetc/analog/roodbridgetc_9m1z1u/User_libs/libFlow/meny_local/noam_tc_phy_ana_top/verilog/netlist2" ;


   open(VERILOGA,"$verilog1") or die "Can't open original verilog file $verilog1 - $!\n"; 
   open(VERILOGAA,">$verilog2") or die "Can't open destination verilog file $verilog2 - $!\n"; 


    my $flag = 1;
    my @lines =();

    while (<VERILOGA>) {

    if ($_ =~ /^input|^output|^inout|^module/) {
    print VERILOGAA $_;
    $flag = 1;
    }
   elsif($_ =~ /^\/\/|timescale|^`include|^\s*$/){print VERILOGAA $_ }  ## this is for general information lines in verilog netlist 
   elsif($_ =~ /\s+{?\w+?(\[\d+\])?}?,?\s?\)?;?$/){print VERILOGAA $_ } ## this is for supporting the case that the "module line contain \n  char or {} for bus or [*]
   elsif($_ =~ /^\s+\)+?;$/){print VERILOGAA $_ }
   elsif(/^endmodule/) {
        for my $line (@lines) {
         $line = "//$line" unless $flag;
         print VERILOGAA $line;
     }
      print VERILOGAA $_;
       @lines = ();
  }
  else{
    push @lines, $_; 

if(/^nch_mac
   |^nch_18_mac
   |^nch_svt_mac
   |^nch_ulvt_dnw_mac
   |^nch_lvt_mac
   |^pch_lvt_mac
   |^pch_18_mac
   |^pch_svt_mac
   |^nch_18_mac
   |^pch_ulvt_mac
   |^nch_ulvt_mac
   |^crtmom_wo_rf
   |^cfmom_2t_p80
   |^nch_gate_sw
   |^rhim_m
   |^rhim_rf
   |^nch_svt_dnw_mac
   |^pwdnw
   |^nch_lvt_dnw_mac
   |^pch_18ud12_mac
   |^pch_18ud15_mac
   |^nch_ulvt_dnw_mac
    /gx){

        $flag = 0;
       }#if
    }#else
}#while



  close VERILOGA;
   close ;
```